# Using linq to xml with Htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack for creatin a htmldocument from the string, like:

```
   HtmlDocument updoc = new HtmlDocument();
   updoc.load(stringContents);
```

Now i want to insert the HtmlNodes as a child of XElement. I tried :

```
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.load(path);
   XElement body = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "body").Single();
   body.Add(updoc.GetElementbyId("h"));
   body.Add(updoc.GetElementbyId("m"));
   body.Add(updoc.GetElementbyId("f"));
```

but result will only the object names (HtmlNodeAgilityPack, ..), not works. Basically i am trying to using the combination of HtmlAgilityPack with linq to xml. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just googling around for stuff, so this may not work for you.  But you need to use the properties of the [HtmlNode](http://www.pacman.schlet.net/docs/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.html) returned by `GetElementbyId()` to create your element.

So something like this:

```
HtmlNode node = updoc.GetElementbyId("h");
XElement e;
body.Add(e = new XElement(node.Name, XElement.Parse(node.InnerHtml)));
```

If the node has [HtmlAttribute](http://www.pacman.schlet.net/docs/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAttribute.html)(s), add them like:

```
foreach(HtmlAttribute att in node.Attributes)
{
    e.Add(new XAttribute(att.Name, att.Value));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a StringBuilder to generate your xml and parse it with [XDocument.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)

```
Example :

StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
//Build xml with the builder
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.